# Centering active element inside custom React carousel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a simple custom React carousel:
https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-wood-740s2?fontsize=14

It goes through numbers from 1 to 100. I'm trying to have an active number centered with large font size, and its neighbors with smaller font size:
[image]

To progress through this carousel, you have to click on the carousel.

The issue is that progressing through the carousel numbers starts to misalign. I suppose that it is because of the wrong calculation for `left` property.

I've tried to tweak the formula, use React Transition Group, and find some existing package which could solve this issue, but I haven't succeeded. I would appreciate any help.

Component code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {
  Wrapper,
  NumbersWrapper,
  NumbersScroller,
  NumberText
} from "./Numbers.style";

const hundred = new Array(100)
  .fill(0)
  .map((k, v) => ({ key: v, label: v + 1 }));

class Numbers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeNumber: 0
    };
  }

  setActiveNumber(number) {
    this.setState({
      activeNumber: number
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { activeNumber } = this.state;
    const intAciveNumber = Number(activeNumber);

    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <NumbersWrapper
          onClick={() => this.setActiveNumber(intAciveNumber + 1)}
        >
          <NumbersScroller
            style={{
              left: `${130 - intAciveNumber * 55}px`
            }}
          >
            {hundred.map(({ key, label }) => {
              const isNeighbor =
                key + 1 === activeNumber || key - 1 === activeNumber;
              const isActive = key === activeNumber;

              return (
                <NumberText
                  key={key}
                  isNeighbor={isNeighbor}
                  isActive={isActive}
                >
                  {label}
                </NumberText>
              );
            })}
          </NumbersScroller>
        </NumbersWrapper>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default Numbers;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Numbers />, rootElement);
```

Numbers.style.js:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  height: 549px;
  width: 612px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  background-color: #ffffff;

  margin-top: 116px;
  padding: 26px 0 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;

  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
  overflow: hidden;
`;

export const NumbersWrapper = styled.div`
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 359.5px;

  overflow: hidden;
`;

export const NumbersScroller = styled.div`
  transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  position: relative;
  left: 130px;
`;

const numberTextStyle = props => {
  if (props.isNeighbor) {
    return `
      height: 88px;
      width: 53px;
      opacity: 0.45;
      color: #6C879C;

      font-size: 80px;
      font-weight: 300;
      letter-spacing: -1.6px;
      line-height: 88px;
      text-align: center;
    `;
  }
  if (props.isActive) {
    return `
      height: 156px;
      color: #6C879C;

      font-size: 150px;
      font-weight: 300;
      letter-spacing: -3px;
      line-height: 156px;
      text-align: center;
    `;
  }

  return `
      opacity: 0.2;
      color: #6C879C;

      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: 300;
      letter-spacing: -0.8px;
      line-height: 48px;
      text-align: center;
    `;
};

export const NumberText = styled.span`
  font-family: Avenir;
  margin: 0 15px;
  user-select: none;

  &:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  &:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  ${props => numberTextStyle(props)}
`;
```

Comment: add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant code. Pardon the inconvinience

Comment: I believe the bug is within this part: `left: ${130 - intAciveNumber * 55}px`, where you calculate `left` as a function of the current number